# Can I carry protein powder in my check-in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, india, air-india

I am travelling to India next week from UK. One of my best pals have asked me to get [Protein powder](http://shop.maxinutrition.com/maxinutrition/strength-and-power/cyclone) for him.

Just wanted to know if I am allowed to carry it in my hand or check-in luggage. It will be a new sealed tub.

**EDIT:**

- Is there any regulations around this which airlines follow?
- Will there be any customs duty involved?
- Should I declare this on immigration card?

**UPDATE**
I was able to pass through customs without any issues. I was not given any immigration card to declare anything.

Comment: Are you asking about airline regulations, custom duty or both?

Comment: There are four distinct issues here, and each deserves its own question (although likely each has been answered already in its own question).  1) Are you permitted to transport protein powder via checked luggage? Almost certainly yes. 2) Are you able to carry it in your hand luggage? Almost certainly yes. 3) Are you permitted to import it? Likely, but it may depend on food importation laws, and how it's packaged, etc. 4) Will there be an import duty? This probbly depends on what else you're carrying in, and whether you exceed some importation limits.

Comment: Thanks, That does clears all my doubts.. I am not carrying anything else.

Comment: I have done this before without any trouble, sometimes even using non-original (smaller) containers. However this was to Colombia, Indonesia, Portugal and Ethiopia, I have no experience with India.

Comment: You are not carrying anything else?!

Comment: Well apart from my clothes and other general stuff. I meant, nothing of this sort which can create any issue in immigration/customs.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14298/21976 ?

Comment: Please add you own answer rather than updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pass through customs without any issues. I was not given any immigration card to declare anything.

Comment: Did you declare it and it was ok or did you not declare it and just didn't get pulled out of the line for a spot check?

Answer (score 8):

Whey protein is made from whey, whey is made from milk, and milk is a dairy product. So, you should tick "Yes" to the customs declaration question which asks about dairy products (if you're required to fill out a landing card). Then go through the red channel and show the product to the customs officer.

Note that if you tick "No" or go through the green channel and you are caught with food products, you can be fined under the Indian Customs Act for making a false declaration, *even if the food products are allowed*.

Comment: Those forms we used to fill in (Indian citizens) at landing are no longer required so there is no written declaration any more. Yes walking through green channel would amount to the same but just thought I would mention that we dont need to fill those forms any more.

Comment: @PSC775 Thank you for that information! I have updated the post. Sorry for the long delay.